# Pin and Unpin Panes in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How to create a WPF Application, something like Pin and Unpin panes.
Example :- Properties Explorer,Solution Explorer , Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 Etc

Please Guide me on which Layout Panel I need to use.

Comment: http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an article on how to do this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439873/Simple-Visual-Studio-like-Pane-Resizing-Docking-an. If you want to do something that is a little simpler take the example in the book wpf unleashed 4.

Comment: Hi Could You Please tell me which Chapter its located in book wpf unleashed 4 ?? i would be grateful and learn the topic

Comment: @TYY Sir could u provide some help about this useful project? The many column class in code behind make me confused. I will pay if needed..